# Git, como mover arquivo ou pasta para outro repositório mantendo o histórico?

Tags: git

Tenho 2 repositórios:

> /var/www/projeto
>
> /var/www/projeto_desativados

Eu tenho um arquivo em uma pasta específica dentro do meu repositório **projeto** e eu quero mover esse arquivo com todo o seu histórico git do repositório **projeto** para o repositório **projeto_desativados**, como eu poderia fazer isso ? Tem jeito ?

Isso me ajudaria a manter as versões anteriores de um projeto antigo que tem mais de 10 anos. e se caso der algum erro eu poderia voltar com o arquivo para o repositório official dinovo com todo o seu histórico.

Comment: Por que você não simplesmente apaga esse arquivo? Ele sempre estará lá no repositório caso queira voltar e consultar o conteúdo dele.

Comment: Interessante, mas ai teremos que começar a trabalhar de outra forma, e vai ser difícil do pessoal aceitar fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Ok, mas o pessoal está usando Git errado. A ideia do controle de versão não é ter "pastas". Se o código não é mais útil para o projeto, o ideal é removê-lo mesmo, e o controle de versão está aí pra, caso no futuro você perceba que aquilo é útil, a informação não foi embora pra sempre. É semelhante a usar controle de versão e mesmo assim deixar trechos de código "comentados" pra caso voltem a ser útil. Vai contra a ideia da ferramenta.

Comment: Eu achei uma solução, mas concordo plenamente com você o controle de versão este aí para isso, o problema é que sou praticamente um novato na empresa e no início quando surgiram com isso eu não tinha conhecimento e nem argumentos para isso. Vou aplicar a solução que achei aqui e vou dar um alerta no pessoal sobre o que você disse, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu achei uma solução que esta nesse link aqui:

[How to Move Changes Between Repositories Git Cherry-Pick](http://www.ifdattic.com/how-to-move-changes-between-repositories-git-cherry-pick/)

Como eu disse para o amigo acima sei que estamos trabalhando da forma errada, mas quando isso foi proposto eu tinha acabado de entrar como estagiário e não tinha conhecimento bastante para questionar ou argumentar, mas enfim vou conversar com o pessoal e aplicar a solução que achei.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode simplesmente fazer um clone do seu repositório remoto em outro diretório na sua máquina:

```
mkdir <repositorio-backup> -- cria o diretorio para o backup
cd <repositorio-backup>
git clone "https://github.com/path"
```

Outra solução seria criar uma branch de backup, por exemplo:

```
git checkout -b "branch-backup-master-2018/01/31"
```

Comment: Sim mas o problema é que o projeto é enorme e estamos atualizando mudando sempre ou seja, sempre estamos pegando classes e arquivos antigos e passando para o repositório de lixo ou seja o repositório de arquivos desativados.

Comment: Que tal a sugestão de utilizar uma branch só com a finalidade de armazenar os arquivos desativados? Resolveria o seu problema?

Comment: Resolveria, o problema é que não trabalhamos dessa forma, já faz anos que trabalhamos com repositórios separados e só agora percebemos que o histórico não ia para lá, pois antes apenas pegavamos e jogavamos lá.